# Growth Rate problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

I have a real world case which I've formulated as below:

[image: Formula]

The left side of the equation is my income and the right side is my expenses, with 0.1 being my expected growth rate of those terms, and x being my unknown growth rate of those terms.

I want to find the max x growth rate such that, my income will always be greater than my expenses, as n increases

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)